# libc::recvmmsg expect MSG_WAITFORONE argument to be u32 but found i32

Tags: solana-program

I cross-compile in Mac OS system. the version for solana is v1.13.5, rustc is v1.63.0.
I want to compile a linux static target in Mac.

step1.  `rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` 
step2. `brew install FiloSottile/musl-cross/musl-cross` 
step3. `ln -s /usr/local/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc  /usr/local/bin/musl-gcc` 
step4.  add a .cargo/config.toml file in the root fold of project with below content.

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
```

step5. `cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

everthing goes smoothly now. when complie solana-streamer v1.14.7, the error occur. see below pic.
[image]

if I adopt the the suggestion(add **.try_into().unwrap()**) in error msg. it compile without error.
any suggestion that needn't to change the third party code. appreciate your effort.

Comment: Actually, now that I read it, I think your suggestion is a great idea! Please put in a PR for this. You'll probably need to add a `#[allow(clippy::...)]` somewhere for this to work on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this might be an issue in the libc `recvmmsg` implementation differing in musl vs other platforms: https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2014/06/07/5

Comment: ok, maybe this is a issue.